# Custom sort of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array looking like:

```
[0] => array( 23 , 890 )
[1] => array( 56 , 401 )
[2] => array( 56 , 491 )
[3] => array( 98 , 840 )
[4] => array( 56 , 821 )
[5] => array( 98 , 401 )
[6] => array( 23 , 875 )
```

I want to sort by the first element and then by the second, BUT (here comes the million dollar question) when the second element has the number 9 in the middle (x9x) I want to sort it last. Like this:

```
[6] => array( 23 , 875 )
[0] => array( 23 , 890 ) // !!!
[1] => array( 56 , 401 )
[4] => array( 56 , 821 ) // note that 821 is before 491, even though it is greater
[2] => array( 56 , 491 ) // !!!
[5] => array( 98 , 401 )
[3] => array( 98 , 840 )
```

I've been trying to fiddle with usort (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), but with no success. When comparing $a to $b in the cmp-function, I did:

```
if( $a[0] > $b[0] )
    return 1;
elseif( $a[0] < $b[0] )
    return -1;
else
    if( $a[1][1] == 9 ) // this did not do what I wanted
        return 1;
    if( $a[1] > $b[1] )
        return 1;
    elseif( $a[1] < $b[1] )
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
```

I could really use some help!

Comment: Have you `var_dump($a[1][1])`? Maybe it's not what you expect and you should explicitly convert `$a[1]` to string?

Comment: `[1]` would only work if the value is a string; so cast the number to a string first. Also take into account that `$b` and/or *both* items may have a `9` in the middle, in which case you need to return `-1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: `strval($a[1])[1] == 9` should make it work

Comment: `var_dump($a[1][1])` gives string(1) "9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works ok for me, see https://3v4l.org/jufbu

```
<?php
uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if( $a[0] != $b[0] )
        return $a[0] - $b[0];
    else
        if( strval($a[1])[1] == 9 )
            return 1;
        else
            return $a[1] - $b[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function that you use for usort, Use this

```
  if( $a[0] > $b[0] )
   return 1;
else if( $a[0] < $b[0] )
   return -1;
else if( $a[1]%10 == 9 )
    return -1;
if( $a[1] > $b[1] )
    return 1;
if( $a[1] < $b[1] )
    return -1;
else
    return 0;
```

Comment: Don't forget to [indent your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90407/easy-way-to-indent-code), it will become more readable!

Answer (score -3):

you can change key as first value in array, and sort array by key.

```
<?php

$yourArray = array(
     array( 23 , 890),
     array( 56 , 401 ),
     array( 56 , 491 ),
     array( 98 , 840 ),
     array( 56 , 821 ),
     array( 56 , 821 ),
     array( 23 , 875 )
);

$resultArray = array();

foreach($yourArray as $_key => $_childArray) {
   $key = $_childArray[0].'.'.$_key;

   if(strpos($_childArray[1],'9')) {
       $key = $_childArray[0].'.9'.$_key;
   }

   $resultArray[$key] = $_childArray;
}

ksort($resultArray);

print_r($resultArray);
```

see when http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/238ca95a59c7bc4cd6f1e23d99d3d91021825503

Comment: I don't think this takes into account the `9` in the middle of the numbers

Comment: And how about `when the second element has the number 9 in the middle (x9x) I want to sort it last.`?